# Is there another way to create an object with a classname returned by a method?

Tags: php

I have this method :

```
public function getInstance()
{
    $classname = $this->getFullyQualifiedClassName();
    return new $classname();
}
```

Is there a way to write this without the `$classname` variable, which gets used only once?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in doing it with $classname. If you want a class instanciation from a string variable, you don't really have a choice. Or you could do a factory with a huuuuuge if statement

Comment: @inkubux : "No, there is no way (at least no shorter way)" would be a perfectly fine answer, provided you can quote some official source that demonstrates that "I don't really have the choice". Please do so if you can, I'll certainly accept your answer. The thing is I googled for it and found nothing interesting, so this question could be a good reference.

Comment: Your example is using the variable twice: First for an assignment, then for access. If it would be used once only, *then* you don't need it, but you use it *twice* and that's very ok and makes your code more readable - which *is* important. So I would say, you don't have an issue here.

Comment: @hakre: By _used_ I meant _accessed_, but I think you already know that, don't you ? Your other sentence makes your comment not completely useless though...

Comment: @greg0ire: ;) I needed to draw a sharp line here (assignment does qualify as variable use for me if I take it strictly) and it helped to conclude to the second part which really is more important than to discuss about what counts as use or not (which can be subjective). I don't find your code ugly in any way. For each line it's clear what it does and the variable looks sensefully named.

Comment: @hakre : I guess you must be right, it there were a more compact solution, it would look like this : `new $this->getFullyQualifiedClassName()();`, which is not very easy to read.

Comment: @greg0ire: Not easy to read *and* it does not work in PHP, which I think is a dead-proof argument ;)

Comment: @hakre : hence the conditional in my sentence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Reflection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php):

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('SomeClassName'); 
$reflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(array(1, 2, 3));
```

But as far as I know, that will be a lot slower than the solution you already have. In a perfect world you could just write something like this:

```
return new ( $this->getFullyQualifiedClassName() )(); // THIS DOES NOT WORK!!!
```

But unfortunately PHP's syntax isn't very flexible, and therefore you have to create that ugly variable thats troubling you.

---

I just realized that there is another (*very ugly*) way to do it: **eval**:

```
return eval("return new ".$this->getFullyQualifiedClassName()."();");
```

I do not suggest that you used this though, because of the [security risk](http://php.robm.me.uk/#toc-eval) that comes with using eval.

Comment: I was just wondering if there was something less ugly I could write. I try never to create a variable that is not used at least twice.

Comment: In that case your only other option is the ReflectionClass, but as far as I know, it is orders of magnitude slower than your initial solution.

Comment: +1, you answered the question, that was a bit ill-posed. What I really want is something short and as performant as the original code, but I think it does not exist. As I said, I would certainly accept an answer saying so backed up with evidence from a trusted source.

Comment: I saw you edited your question, I'll stick with what I have know. A choice between ugly and uglier, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Give your `getFullyQualifiedClassName` method a parameter whether return object or string.

```
public function getFullyQualifiedClassName($return_object = false) {
    //............
    return $return_object ? new $classname() : $classname;
}
```

then

```
public function getInstance()
{
    return $this->getFullyQualifiedClassName(true);
}
```

But I think this way is not better than your have a `$classname` in your `getInstance` method if your `getFullyQualifiedClassName` just need to return string of the class name.

**Edit:**
As @x3ro said, it violates the method name, another way is to use a Help method, but it still worth little. Actually the `$classname` is not so ugly.

```
public function getInstance()
{
    return Util::NewObjectFromName($this->getFullyQualifiedClassName());
}
```

Comment: -1 You are returning an **Object** from a method that states (by its name) that it will return a **Class Name**. Very bad practice, IMO.

Comment: +1 for giving me a workaround for this problem, but this is a workaround, not a solution.